# Maven to integrate multiple Git Projects

Tags: git, maven, module, git-submodules

Hi: I have several git projects which i want to integrate under a single maven build.  What are the available templates for doing this, and is there an existing archetype that describes this sort of build?

Comment: I think I would start with GIT submodules first - then try to look into Maven. The maven release plugin seems to support submodules since version 2.2: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-457

Answer (score 0):

I would use [maven modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) for this solution. If you build then the parent, all childs will also be build.

[Here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) You can find a small example how to work with maven submodules.

Can this be a solution for you?